# SSRS conditional colour filling

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a specific requirement to fill the color if the difference is less than 300 then transparent, if in between 300 to 500 then "yellow" and above 500 then "red".

I am using the below switch expression but it is not working out.

```
=Switch(
 Fields!Difference.Value <-300,"Transparent",
 Fields!Difference.Value >-300,"Yellow",
 Fields!Difference.Value >-500,"Red",
 True,"Transparent"
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    =Switch(
     Fields!Difference.Value <300,"Transparent",
     Fields!Difference.Value >=300 and Fields!Difference.Value <500,"Yellow",
     Fields!Difference.Value >=500,"Red"
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
   =Switch(
     Fields!Difference.Value <300,"Transparent",
     Fields!Difference.Value <500,"Yellow",
     Fields!Difference.Value >500,"Red"
     )
```